# How many times split has been used in breaking a sentence

Tags: python, split

Usage of split with a string in python, converts a string in to a list, with the delimiters specified in the split statement.

How to we determine as how many times split has been employed in splitting a sentence using python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of the returned `list` minus `1`.

```
>>> s = "this is a test string"
>>> s.split()
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
>>> len(s.split()) - 1
4
```

Therefore `len(s.split()) - 1` would be `4`, because there were `4` spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
s ="foo bar foobar"
print (s.split())
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'] # three elements 
print len(s.split())-1  # get len of the list - 1, three elements but two splits
```

You can also pass a `maxsplit` argument to `split`:

```
s ="foo bar foobar"
print (s.split(" ",2))  # split on first two

['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

print(s.split(" ",1)) # split on first only
['foo', 'bar foobar']
```